# Well-Ordering Principle for Non-negative Integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Let $\Bbb Z_0$ be the set of all nonnegative integers and $\emptyset \ne S \subseteq \Bbb Z_0$. Then $S$ has a least element.

**Definition.** A set $A \subseteq \Bbb Z_0$ is called *inductive* if $0 \in A$ and $x \in A \implies x+1\in A$.

**Attempt:**
Let $A=\{n \in \Bbb Z_0 \mid n\le s, \forall s \in S\}$. Suppose for the contrary that $S$ has no least element. Since $0$ is the least element in $\Bbb Z_0$ and $S \subseteq \Bbb Z_0$, we have $0 \le s$ for any $s \in S$. Hence, $0 \in A$.

Now, let $x \in A$, then $x \le s$ for any $s \in S$. Since $S$ has no least element, we have $x<s$ for any $s \in S$.
Hence, $x+1 \le s$ for all $s \in S$.
So, $x+1 \in A$. Thus, $A$ is an inductive set. Hence, $A=\Bbb Z_0$. Since $S \ne \emptyset$, we can pick $a \in S \subseteq \Bbb Z_0$ such that $a+1 \in \Bbb Z_0$. Since $A = \Bbb Z_0$, then $a+1 \in A$. Therefore, $a+1 \le a<a+1$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, $S$ has a least element.

I already know the Well-Ordering Principle for positive integer $\Bbb N$. But, I don't know yet that this approach above correct. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: There is a natural order preserving bijection from the positive integers to the non-negative integers $f:\mathbb Z_{ge 1} \to \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$, namely $f(n)=n-1$.  Or you can say that the least element of $S$ does not change if $0 \not \in S$ and is $0$ if $0 \in S$

Comment: You provided a correct proof if it is "underlying" that $\mathbb Z_0$ has no proper subset that is inductive.

Comment: @Henry Since $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z_0$ is equipotent, then the same method for proof of WOP of $\Bbb N$ also works for $\Bbb Z_0$?